# How can I check if a process is running in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have a script which checks for a jar file and if its running echo's running else will execute the jar file. But the following command seems to return a different value every time I run my script

`ps aux | grep some.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`

When I just run `ps aux` I can see a few no of same jar files but only one process is running.

Any there other ways to check for running jar file?

Can I use `pgrep -fl java` instead of the above command?

Comment: Use lock files. Also use `grep [s]ome.jar` so eliminate the need to `grep -v`. Finally, you can use `grep -c` to output a count...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
ps aux | grep [s]ome.jar | wc -l
```

i just tested it myself and should do the trick :-)

Comment: Please read the man page for `ps`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like something like pgrep -f java.*jarname

pgrep -fl java will return all the processes whose command line includes "java".